# Как сделать чтобы скрипт работал отдельно для каждой пары табов?

Tags: html, jquery, tabs

Всем привет. Сейчас скрипт срабатывает для всех элементов, т.е. листаются они сверху и снизу. Подскажите плиз как сделать чтобы они работали по-отдельности ?

```js
$("div.menu a").click(function(){
 $("div.slides").css({"left":-100*$(this).index()+"%"});
});
```

```css
div.menu{display:block;margin:0px 0px 20px 0px;}
div.menu a{display:inline-block;margin-right:20px;}
div.main{width:856px;height:360px;background:#ebebeb;overflow:hidden;box-shadow:0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5);position:relative;}
div.main div.slides{display:block;width:100%;height:100%;white-space:nowrap;position:absolute;transition:all .5s;left:0%;}
div.main div.slides div{font-size:100px;width:100%;height:100%;display:inline-block;text-align:center;}
div.main div.slides div:nth-child(1){background:#ff1100;}
div.main div.slides div:nth-child(2){background:#ffff11;}
div.main div.slides div:nth-child(3){background:#11ff11;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
<a href="#">first</a><a href="#">second</a><a href="#">third</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
 <div class="slides">
 <div>first</div><div>second</div><div>third</div>
 </div>
</div>

<br>
<hr>
<br>

<div class="menu">
<a href="#">first</a><a href="#">second</a><a href="#">third</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
 <div class="slides">
 <div>first</div><div>second</div><div>third</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: использовать методы jquery `closest()`, `parent()` и `find()`. На SO уже был аналогичный вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример

```js
$('.menu').on('click', '.menu-link:not(.current)', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current')
    .parents('.tabs-container').find('div.slides').css({
      "left": -100 * $(this).index() + "%"
    });

});
```

```css
div.menu {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}

div.menu a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

div.main {
  width: 856px;
  height: 360px;
  background: #ebebeb;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  position: relative;
}

div.main div.slides {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .5s;
  left: 0%;
}

div.main div.slides div {
  font-size: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

div.main div.slides div:nth-child(1) {
  background: #ff1100;
}

div.main div.slides div:nth-child(2) {
  background: #ffff11;
}

div.main div.slides div:nth-child(3) {
  background: #11ff11;
}

.current {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs-container">
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#" class="menu-link current">first</a><a href="#" class="menu-link">second</a><a href="#" class="menu-link">third</a>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="slides">
      <div>first</div>
      <div>second</div>
      <div>third</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<hr>
<br>

<div class="tabs-container">
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#" class="menu-link current">first</a><a href="#" class="menu-link">second</a><a href="#" class="menu-link">third</a>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="slides">
      <div>first</div>
      <div>second</div>
      <div>third</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо добрый человек)